# Lattice and Sublattice

Tags: lattice-orders

I understand the definition of Lattice and Sublattice, but I cannot show the following exercise, since it seems trivial to me.

> Show that, for any subset $S$ of a lattice $L$, the set $s^{l}$ of all
>   the lower bounds of $S$ is a sublattice of $L$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are a new user, and perhaps you never noticed it, but there are upvotes and acceptance of answers which you may find useful (one for question). See '[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)' and other links in the [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 2):

It's indeed easy: if $a$ and $b$ are lower bounds for all $s\in S$, that means $a\le s, \, b\le s$.
Then clearly also $a\land b\le s$ as e.g. $a\land b\le a$, and $a\lor b\le s$ by the definition of least upper bound ($\lor$).